# How to install gas-preprocessor?

Tags: perl, macos, ffmpeg

sorry for the stupid question. I'd like to install the gas-preprocessor (https://github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor) but I just don't get how to do this. What do I have to do with the .pl-file? How do I install the script?
Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Does XCode let you set your assembler in a preferences pane? Near the top of the script, `# usage: set your assembler to be something like "perl gas-preprocessor.pl gcc"` If you can set the assembler in XCode, set it to `perl /path/to/gas-preprocessor.pl gcc`. You can probably store the script in a `~/bin/` directory, or with the project you're working on that needs the different assembler.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well i had the same problem "GNU assembler not found, install gas-preprocessor"

Later it turned out that i didnt had the correct file because i copy pasted the code in text editor

The correct way to do it is:

(a) Use the download button at https://github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor

(b) Extract the archive

(c) Remove any other file by same name which you have downloaded and you were experimenting with.

(d) copy the file gas-preprocessor.pl at /usr/local/bin

(e) Set permission of the file to Read and write by all (777) if a -> d doesn't work

I figured out this problem when i read config.log during compilation of ffmpeg

Comment: hi i have done as you said . still i got same error . any help??

Comment: I would advise to use this version of gas-preprocessor: https://github.com/libav/gas-preprocessor

Answer (score 3):

Run this command to install gas-preprocessor:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FFmpeg/gas-preprocessor/master/gas-preprocessor.pl && \ chmod +x gas-preprocessor.pl && \ sudo mv gas-preprocessor.pl $(which gas-preprocessor.pl)
```

Comment: This answer is very good exceopt the last bit helps if you just move the file 

wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FFmpeg/gas-preprocessor/master/gas-preprocessor.pl && chmod +x gas-preprocessor.pl && sudo mv gas-preprocessor.pl /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after following the above steps in OSX Lion. It seems that my /usr/local/bin directory was only accessible by root on my system (this path seemed to be owned by macports).

After putting gas-preprocessor.pl in /usr/bin the configure process ran fine.