# ffmpeg for iOS (armv6 and armv7)

Tags: ios

I've tried a number of solutions on here to build ffmpeg for iOS. Most notably, the last that I tried was here: [ffmpeg won't ./configure in iOS5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982528/ffmpeg-wont-configure-in-ios5-1?s=e50c8c43-362d-436e-bdfb-ba6dc701890d#new-answer)

When I try the proposed solution and then run "lipo -info" on one of the output libraries I get:

input file armv7/libavcodec.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: armv7/libavcodec.a is architecture: i386

Is this the expected result of running "lipo -info" on a file built for amrv7?

Answer (score 0):

Did you possibly build for the simulator i386 rather than armv7 .

Also if your using Xcode 4.4 it's very important that you include armv7s or remove the armv7s arch from your build settings.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you did not install gas-preprocessor.pl .
See this answer how to install:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5307801/1597017

In my project, I used rake for configure and build ffmpeg for iOS with Xcode 4.5.1 (sdk 6.0)
A link: https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie/blob/master/Rakefile